# PHP: How to dynamically assign variables into array

Tags: php, arrays, variables, indexing

This is killing me, for the life of me i can not seem to figure out how to get this to work, or why it doesn't work in the first place.

Here is what i'm trying to do:

here is my variables declaration:

```
$locale = 'US';
$realm = 'magtheridon';
$character = 'billymayys';
```

here is my array declaration:

```
$my_array = ( 'L' => $locale, 'R' => $realm, 'C' => $character );
```

I am new to php and from what i can tell this should create an array who would print out to:

```
Array( 
      [L] => US, 
      [R] => magtheridon, 
      [C] => billymayys, 
      );
```

But it doesn't.

What is the proper way to create an array, whos index i can name and then assign variables to the values of those indexs?

The array declaration:

```
$my_array = ( 'L' => 'US', 'R' => 'magtheridon', 'C' => 'billymayys' );
```

Works but i do not understand why i cannot dynamically assign the values using variables.

Please help! Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure they are in the same scope? You're not trying to define the array in a function with the variables from outside the function, are you?

Comment: did you try `$my_array = array('L' => $locale, 'R' => $realm, 'C' => $character );` ?

Comment: what does it actually print? did u try var_dump($my_array)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just have a minor syntax error, missing the `array` keyword.

Change:

```
$my_array = ( 'L' => $locale, 'R' => $realm, 'C' => $character );
```

To:

```
$my_array = array( 'L' => $locale, 'R' => $realm, 'C' => $character );
```

Or:

```
$my_array = [ 'L' => $locale, 'R' => $realm, 'C' => $character ]; // PHP 5.4+
```

Working example: http://3v4l.org/d2UWM

Comment: Can't believe I missed that when I commented XD

Comment: Much thanks. The absence of array was actually just a typo on my part when I created the question. BUT, it lead me to finding the real problem. I am using wordpress and my assignments were wrong, i was using $locale = the_author_meta(  $current_user->id, 'locale'  );, when i should have used $locale = $current_user->locale;

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `array` keyword:

```
$my_array = array( 'L' => $locale, 'R' => $realm, 'C' => $character );
```

Not sure why the second one would work!

Comment: The absence of the `array` keyword along with using:

`$locale = the_author_meta($current_user,'locale');` 
instead of:
`$locale=$current_user->locale;` seems to have been the issue. Thanks for all the help. 

*im working with wordpress.